# Access HTML by id through SASS

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, jsx, tsx

Is there a possibility to access an HTML element by id through SASS? I use SASS in combination with React in TSX files. Normally for styling I would define a SASS entry and add that entry to the list of classes, as shown in the following example:

Report.sass:

```
.city {
    color: red;
}
```

Report.tsx:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as Style from "./Report.scss";

export class Report extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <div className={Style.city}>Test text for cities</div>;
    }
}
```

This example works perfectly fine. But if I now gave the `div` tag an id, I would need to also change the SASS file accordingly. This through fails, as shown here:

Report.sass:

```
#city {
    color: red;
}
```

Report.tsx:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as Style from "./Report.scss";

export class Report extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <div id="city">Test text for cities</div>;
    }
}
```

I believe that the SASS file forgets about the `#city` entry as there is no pointer in the `Report.tsx` to it. Am I right with this assumption? How could I make the SASS command work with the `city` id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think theres some misunderstandings about css and html.

You can have both a `class` and `id` tag for each html element.

Therefore it will compile fine if you have the following:

```
<div id="NewYork" className={Style.city}>
```

This is an unorthodox way to apply styles in React though. The easier way is to import the stylesheet via

```
import './Report.scss';
```

then you can use your styles more freely like so:

```
<div id="NewYork" className="city">
```

Comment: Your second example does not work with my settings. If I change from `import * as Style from "./Report.scss";` to `import './Report.scss';` and from `<div className={Style.city}>Test text for cities</div>` to `<div className="city">Test text for cities</div>` the CSS properties vanish and have no effect the result. Is there any special project setting necessary for this to work?

Comment: You could try `require('./Report.scss')` but the `import` way should work if its not giving you an error. The `.city { ... }` would apply to `className="city"`